# Django Template Not Found

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I have a Django problem which only occasionally has problems finding Templates. It will be running fine for hours, and then suddenly not be able to serve certain templates.  Occasionally the problem will correct itself, but can *always* be fixed by running `touch <template>`.  My current solution is a cronjob which executes `touch <project root>` every minute, and that works so long as cron keeps up.  However, I want to figure out a proper solution to my problem.

Relevant Settings:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
APPS_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    (PROJECT_ROOT + '/templates'),
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "base_site.context_processors.app_list"
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Comment: do you have the staticfiles finder in your settings?
`STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)`

Comment: try to add a folder named "templates" inside app directory and not in project_root directory. If it works, then run "manage.py collectstatics" to group all app static files in one

Comment: I don't believe the problem is with static files? The issue is django throws TemplateDoesNotExist, and in detail says django could not find a template at `<project_root>/templates/admin/.../<template file>.html`  even though that file exists.  Most of the templates I have modify pages within the admin, my understanding was that putting them under project root would be the only way for django to find the correct template?

Comment: @Astraub You are overriding default template dir with your own, so now on it will search app directory only ( not project dir ) Are you aware that ? but admin template you can place inside project dir only. !

Comment: I've tried adding the admin templates in to an app within PROJECT_ROOT/apps to no avail, django still throws TemplateDoesNotExist listing both the template in the app, and the one at PROJECT_ROOT/templates as files it checked for.

Comment: This is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484277/11132361 I have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out my problem was not with Django itself but with my environment.  I was running the Django server from ~/Django-project, and our dev server encrypts home directories once all sessions are signed out which means the service could no longer find it.  Moving the project to /var/ and daemonizing the manage.py runserver command has kept the project free of Template Does Not Exist errors.

Comment: that sounds like a painful and error prone system architecture

Answer (score 49):

Just wanted to add another case where you may get the `Template Does Not Exist` error.

Make sure you've added your app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` variable inside your `settings.py` file. The `startapp` command is not enough.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myappname', # add your app here :)
]
```

I know it's silly, but I know people that have failed their driver's test because of forgetting to fasten their seat belt, so forgetting a line of code isn't as rare as it sounds.

Answer (score 8):

Try updating your settings like so:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),)
```

(This is the default way of getting the BASE_DIR in django 1.8). Prior to Python 3.4, `__file__` is not guaranteed to give the absolute file path.

You should also try and remain platform agnostic by using os.path.join rather than adding the directory as a string (other platforms use backslashes).