# Django templates does not exist

Tags: django, windows, python-3.x, django-templates, pycharm

So I work on windows and I try to load my websit home page. However I get the ''Templates doesnot exist '' errors I don't know why,

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
home/home.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.10.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
home/home.html
Exception Location: C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 25
Python Executable:  C:\Python35\python.exe
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:
```

[Here is my Tracerback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVUbx.png)

you can see there that Django cannot even load some templates to be tested with. I'v seen others who have the same problem but at leat there was a list of tried template me I don't even have this.

here is my home/views.py

```
class IndexView(View):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    # not logged in
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

here is my templates variable in my setting.py

```
TEMPLATE = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

in my code and my structure is 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj4Lg.png) and you can see that I added Home in the installed_app

yet after changing the path root of project, changing my python version (3.5 instead of 2.7) put a templates folder on the same level of my manage.py and change APPS_DIR to false i still get nothing. I have try to know if it was a path problem so I  put the file in the root of project and test with isFile function of python  and the return was true but if I try to render the page the same link I get the error.So I don't know if it's my code, my configuration of my project(virtual environnement, django etc)  and It really  gets annoying I use pycharm and I'm on windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this path in settings.py to properly call the template:

```
'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
        ],
```

Comment: done that and still nothing.. I don't know maybe my  problem is the same as this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973522/django-template-not-found) but I don't understand how he managed to get his problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to place your apps on an `apps` package. Try replacing your applications architecture to something like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'applications.events',
   'applications.student',
   'applications.resume',
   'applications.home`,
]
```

instead of `"something.apps.somethingelse"`.

that is Pythonic.